# How to solve TARGETINVOCATIONEXCEPTION in javaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a confusing error in my JavaFX with FXML code while running the program.
I have three files:
First one named: **F2XML.fxml** which contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafxapplication5.FXMLDocumentController ?>
<GridPane fx:controller = "FXMLDocumentController" hgap="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="600.0" vgap="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="20.0" minHeight="8.0" prefHeight="8.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="12.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="0.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <Label text="Choose gender:" />
        <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="Female" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
            <toggleGroup>
                <ToggleGroup fx:id="gender" />
            </toggleGroup>
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Male" toggleGroup="$gender" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="" onMouseClicked="#BClickedActionHandler" text="OK" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
    </children>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
    </padding>
</GridPane>
```

The second file name is: **FXMLDocumentController.java** which contains:

```
package javafxapplication5;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    RadioButton Male;
    @FXML
    RadioButton Female;
    @FXML
    Button OK;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    @FXML
    public void BClickedActionHandler() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

And the third one is: **JavaFXApplication5.java** which contains:

```
package javafxapplication5;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication5 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = null;
        Scene scene = null;
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("F2XML.fxml"));
        loader.setController(new FXMLDocumentController());
        Pane mainPane = loader.load();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

When running the program I was struggling with the following code:

```
Executing D:\Java\JavaFXApplication5\dist\run1638782428\JavaFXApplication5.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/D:/Java/JavaFXApplication5/dist/run1638782428/JavaFXApplication5.jar!/javafxapplication5/F2XML.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2543)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at javafxapplication5.JavaFXApplication5.start(JavaFXApplication5.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:604)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:88)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2513)
    ... 12 more
Exception running application javafxapplication5.JavaFXApplication5
Java Result: 1
```

**Can someone help in solving this error?**

Answer (score 0):

It says right there in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
```

Which means that your input file is not like the parser expects it to be. Load it into an XML editor, or even Internet Explorer, to see if your file is valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

`InvocationTargetExceptions` are thrown in methods where code is executed that is unknown during compile-time and therefor the exceptions being thrown by the method can't be declared in a throws-clause or catched when calling. So you have to go "down" the stacktrace to look for the relevant "Caused by"-block.

In this case it's

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
```

The XML that is parsed seems to be corrupt. I checked the XML you provided in your question and that looks OK to me (and to Internet Explorer that would complain in case of such an error).

Make sure that the XML you provided here is actually the XML that resides within the Jar-file where it was read from as you can see in the exception-block "above" the last one:

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/D:/Java/JavaFXApplication5/dist/run1638782428/JavaFXApplication5.jar!/javafxapplication5/F2XML.fxml
```

Maybe you have your XML within the file-system but the corresponding classpath-entry after `JavaFXApplication5.jar` and you're looking at the wrong XML as reason for the error.